# Can i upload a password protected pdf using google drive api?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

So i've tried uploading a normal non password protected pdf file and it successfully gets uploaded using the below code. 
However if i try the same with a password protected file google throws a 400 error code (Bad Request)
refrence: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

```
 $content = file_get_contents($file_path);
 $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                        'name' => 'dummy_name',
                        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'));

 $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
                        'data' => $content,
                        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
                        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                        'fields' => 'id'));
```

Is it possible to upload a pdf with password protection even if i have the password with me?

Comment: I'm not sure how the client library handles upload for password protected pdf or files. Try asking in their [GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues), may be contributors in their GitHub have encountered this kind of situation. If not, it maybe a bug or at least they will be notified that this kind of scenario you are experiencing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the mimeType set to "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet". 
I think it should work if you set it to "application/pdf"

In my case, password protected file upload seems to work with PDFs, but not with DOCX files.